# Mock Promise, but run actual code inside then block

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am new to javascript testing frame. I am facing an issue with mocking of Promise. My code looks like this :

```js
this.convertEvent(
    () => {
        addUser(this.getProp("criterion")).then((reply) => {
            if (reply[0].m_status === "S") {
                this.getUser();
            }
        });
    });
```

In my unit test, when I am making a call to convertEvent, I need to execute two methods addUser and getUser(this gets executed when reply comes from addUser). I am using spyOn() something like this:

```
let thenFunc;
        beforeEach(() => {
            promiseSpyObj.then.and.callFake((func) => {
                thenFunc = func;
                return [{ m_status : "S" }];
            });
            let arrayReply = [{ m_status : "S" }];
            spyOn(className, "addUser").and.returnValue(promiseSpyObj);
            spyOn(className, "getUser").and.returnValue(promiseSpyObj);
```

And I am expecting:
`expect(className.addUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(className.getUser).toHaveBeenCalled();`

But what I am noticing is only addUser() gets called. What I am expecting is addUser promise should resolve and getUser should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the way you have mentioned in spec , addUser should be like `this.addUser` . 
Then, your spec can be as below:

```
let reply = [{m_status : "S"}]
spyOn(className, "getUser")
spyOn(className, "addUser").and.returnValue(
    Promise.resolve(reply);
)

className.addUser().then(function () {
    expect(className.getUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

In addition you need to see when you are calling `convertEvent` function.

Comment: @Nikhil kumar, Did it helped any ways ?